# Microsoft Access adding an extra column to existing union select

Tags: sql, ms-access

[enter image description here][1]I need to add 4 columns ( Item name, FullPrice_2018(price), FullPrice_2019(price), (FullPrice_2019-FullPrice_2018) ) to the query.  I can't figure out how to add another column to the union without merging rows.
Right now my table is with 2018 & 2019 items but I need 3 more columns.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTmqB.png

```
SELECT FullPrice_2018.[Item name]
FROM FullPrice_2018
UNION 
SELECT FullPrice_2019.[Item name]
FROM FullPrice_2019
ORDER BY [Item name]


Result should be like this 
"Item name" price2018 price2019 "price2019-price2018"


 https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxKU5.png
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want `JOIN`:

```
SELECT F2018.[Item name], F2018.FullPrice, F2019.FullPrice,
       (F2019.FullPrice - F2018.FullPrice)
FROM FullPrice_2018 as F2018 INNER JOIN
     FullPrice_2019 as F2019
     ON F2018.[Item name] = F2019.[Item name] 
ORDER BY F2018.[Item name];
```

Unfortunately, MS Access doesn't support `FULL JOIN`.  But I think you can do:

```
SELECT [Item name], MAX(FullPrice_2018), MAX(FullPrice_2019),
       (MAX(FullPrice_2019) - MAX(FullPrice_2018))
FROM (SELECT F2018.[Item name], F2018.FullPrice as FullPrice_2018, NULL as FullPrice_2010 
      FROM FullPrice_2018 as F2018
      UNION ALL
      SELECT F2019.[Item name], NULL, F2019.FullPrice as FullPrice_2019
      FROM FullPrice_2019 as F2019
     ) F
GROUP BY [Item name]
ORDER BY [Item name];
```

Not all versions of MS Access support `UNION ALL` in the `FROM` clause, so you might need to use a view for that portion of the query.

Comment: When i use this than, it removes items what are only used in FullPrice2018 or FullPrice2019, i need all the items. It looks like it needs an Union selection like in my question

Answer (score 0):

Create a query that will return a normalised output:

```sql
SELECT 
    FullPrice_2018.[Item name], 2018 As [Year], Price
FROM 
    FullPrice_2018
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    FullPrice_2019.[Item name], 2019 As [Year], Price
FROM 
    FullPrice_2019
```

Save the query and use it as source in a normal *crosstab* query. Use the wizard to create this if you are unfamiliar with crosstab queries.